# Window location to another page with parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

```
string parameter = Request.QueryString["forum_id"];

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Replied!Thank you.');window.location ='eforum_main.aspx?forum_id='+parameter;", true);
```

I'm tried to add parameter when redirect but fail,no idea where i did wrong,my page didn't redirect to that page after i submit my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the `parameter` string correctly in the ScriptManager.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Replied!Thank you.');window.location ='eforum_main.aspx?forum_id=" + parameter + "';", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just writing the `+parameter;` as a plain text to javascript, to avoid confusion, you could use string.Format:

```
string
    parameter = Request.QueryString["forum_id"],
    JavaScriptCommand = "alert('Replied!Thank you.');" + string.Format(
        "window.location='eforum_main.aspx?forum_id={0}';",
        parameter
    );

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", JavaScriptCommand , true);
```